# Mongodb Logs flood

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am starting to use Mongodb to storage my data, and when I started the service, I am getting a log flood, I want to turn off this log saves, I don't mind if I do not have any kind of logs, it is development environment and need to do that, because my log file is growing more than 30gb by 2 or 3 days.

I've tried to change quiet to true as below, but with no success.

```
root@master:~# cat /etc/mongod.conf 
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
journal:
enabled: true
# engine:
# mmapv1:
# wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
verbosity: 0
destination: file
logAppend: true

###### HERE ######
quiet: true

path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# path: /dev/null
component:
accessControl:
verbosity: 1
command:
verbosity: 1
```

Any idea how to get a clean logs?? could be a logs with nothing.

Thank you!!

Comment: What kind of thing is being logged…?

Answer (score 3):

Mongo logs have a number of verbosity levels from 0 to 5.

- 0 is the quietest and
- 5 is the most verbose.
- The default level is 0.

Wherever you are setting verbosity as 1, set it to 0.

You should check the log levels defined using -

```
db.getLogComponents()
```

This would give you the set log levels which you can modify to 0 and see if the logging changes.

```
db.setLogLevel(<verbosity>, <component>)
```

Where component can be one of - `accessControl`, `command`, `control`, `geo`, `index`, `network`, `query`, `replication`, `storage`, `journal`, `write`.